# nVidia proprietary driver

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, nvidia

I successfully installed `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-290.10.run` on my Debian Squeeze desktop but I do not see `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log` clearly stating which file(s) have been added/replaced. Does anybody know which file(s) it installs or modifies ?

Comment: Are you using the Debian nvidia packages, and if not, why not?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha Of course the Debian packages would be best but my graphics card is new and I need a newer package.

Comment: `290.10` is available in testing/unstable, `295.09` in experimental. Use the Debian packages `nvidia-kernel-source` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Nvidia drivers as follows.

Install `nvidia-glx` (metapackage) and the kernel driver source (`nvidia-kernel-source`), It sounds like you will want to get these from unstable or experimental.

Then you can build the binary kernel module using `module-assistant`. First, install `module-assistant`. Then

```
m-a
```

gives you interactive mode.

- First run UPDATE and PREPARE
- Go into SELECT, and pick `nvidia-kernel`.
- Then run BUILD and then INSTALL.

Make sure `xorg.conf` references `nvidia`in the device section. I.e.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "nVidia Corporation G70 [GeForce 7300 GS]"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "PCI:02:00:0"
```

Comment: A [How to](http://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers) at Debian.org explains various different methods. I still think that it is best to use the `.run` file from nvidia.com instead of installing .deb packages from different Debian repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You can find moved files in `/var/lib/nvidia/`. A log containing touched files can be found at `/var/lib/nvidia/log`.

For a more detailled list from an installation attempt in VirtualBox, see https://lists.launchpad.net/bumblebee/msg00019.html